# Why can't the fructose monomer in sucrose be α-fructose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, molecular-structure, carbohydrates

In all academic sources, sucrose is identified as α−glucose (1-->2) β−fructose. However, I cannot find any explanation anywhere as to why the fructose monomer has to be in the β configuration. Maltose has both α and β anomers, same for lactose. Even trehalose, another non-reducing disaccharide with glycosidic linkage between two anomeric carbons, has α-α, α-β, and even β-β anomers. Why is sucrose special? And is there a disaccharide out there that has α−glucose (1-->2) α−fructose configuration?

Comment: Slides 24-28 [here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/carbohydrates44.pdf) may be of help.